# Como ocultar elementos del onNavigationItemSelected?

Tags: android, android-studio, menú, navigationview

Hola buena tarde estoy trabajando con onNavigationItemSelected y quisiera saber si existe alguna manera de que dependiendo el usuario que accesa a la app sea la vista del menu a presentar.

Comment: Que has intentado? agrega tu código!

Comment: Te sugiero agregar lo que has investigado o realizado, revisar [ask]

Answer (score 3):

Supongamos un escenario con tres tipos de usuarios:

- admin
- editor
- suscriptor

## Opción 1:

Puedes crear un menú con tres grupos. Por defecto, sólo el grupo de opciones de suscriptor, el grupo inferior, será visible para todos. Los demás grupos de opciones los harás visibles según el tipo de usuario.

### nav_view.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group
        android:id="@+id/group_admin"
        android:visible="false">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_borrar"
                android:title="@string/lbl_borrar" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_configurar"
                android:title="@string/lbl_configurar" />
    </group>
    <group
        android:id="@+id/group_editor"
        android:visible="false">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_editar"
            android:title="@string/lbl_editar" />
    </group>
    <group
        android:id="@+id/group_suscriptor"
        android:visible="true">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_leer"
            android:title="@string/lbl_leer" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_imprimir"
            android:title="@string/lbl_imprimir" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

### Código dinámico

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
```

Si el usuario es `admin`:

```
String strUsuarioTipo="admin";

if (strUsuarioTipo.equals("admin")){

    navigationView.getMenu().setGroupVisible(R.id.group_admin, true);
    navigationView.getMenu().setGroupVisible(R.id.group_editor, true);

}
```

Si es `editor`:

```
String strUsuarioTipo="editor";

if (strUsuarioTipo.equals("editor")){
    navigationView.getMenu().setGroupVisible(R.id.group_editor, true);
}
```

Si es `suscriptor` ya el menú viene con sus opciones visibles por defecto.

---

## Opción 2:

Crear menúes por separado y mostrarlos según el caso:

### `nav_suscriptor.xml`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group
        android:id="@+id/group_suscriptor">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_leer"
            android:title="@string/lbl_leer" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_imprimir"
            android:title="@string/lbl_imprimir" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

### `nav_editor.xml`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group
        android:id="@+id/group_editor">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_editar"
            android:title="@string/lbl_editar" />
    </group>
    <group
        android:id="@+id/group_suscriptor">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_leer"
            android:title="@string/lbl_leer" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_imprimir"
            android:title="@string/lbl_imprimir" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

### `nav_admin.xml`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group
        android:id="@+id/group_admin">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_borrar"
                android:title="@string/lbl_borrar" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_configurar"
                android:title="@string/lbl_configurar" />
    </group>
    <group
        android:id="@+id/group_editor">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_editar"
            android:title="@string/lbl_editar" />
    </group>
    <group
        android:id="@+id/group_suscriptor">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_leer"
            android:title="@string/lbl_leer" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_imprimir"
            android:title="@string/lbl_imprimir" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

### Código dinámico

```
//Cargamos el menú mínimo por defecto
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_suscriptor);

    switch (strTipoUsuario) {
         case "admin":
                navigationView.getMenu().clear();
                navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.nav_admin);
                break;

        case "editor":
                navigationView.getMenu().clear();
                navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.nav_editor);
                break;

        default:
                //Habremos cargado nav_suscriptor por defecto
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu respuesta me fue de mucha utilidad. =)

Comment: Me alegro @CésarManuelRíosGómez. Por favor lee [¿Qué hacer cuando alguien contesta a mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Saludos.