# ¿Es posible en Android poner un menú en el Toolbar directamente a través del archivo XML del layout?

Tags: android, layout

Tengo un menú que se muestra en el `ToolBar` de varias Activitys. En cada `Activity` yo inflo el menú por código y quisiera ver si es posible (y recomendable) poner dicho menú directamente en el layout. Así no tengo que ir a inflarlo a cada Activity.

Explico cómo tengo organizado el asunto actualmente:

Cada Activity tiene un `CoordinatorLayout` que es el que se carga en el `onCreate`. Por ejemplo:

## 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="org.deiverbum.liturgiacatolica.activities.SantoActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/content_zoom_cal_audio" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

## 2

En el layout `content_zoom_cal_audio` que hay en el include, tenemos otro `CoordinatorLayout` con la `ToolBar` y un `RelativeLayout` para un `TextView` dentro de un `ScrollView` ( se admite cualquier crítica :) ):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="org.deiverbum.liturgiacatolica.activities.BreviarioActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/content_liturgia_horas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/txt_salterio"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_liturgia_horas">

        <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <org.deiverbum.liturgiacatolica.utils.ZoomTextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_breviario"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textSize="@dimen/default_font" />
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

## 3

Por otra parte, tengo el XML del menú, que es este:

#### `breviario_menu_action`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".activities.BreviarioActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_voz"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_leer_play"
        android:title="@string/leer"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_calendario"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_show_calendar"
        android:title="@string/all_calendar"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

## 4

Y en cada Activity inflo el menú por código, así:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.breviario_menu_action, menu);
    return true;
}
```

El código así funciona. Pero quisiera saber si es posible (y recomendable) poner el menú directamente en el XML del layout, como hago con los include...

He intentando poniendo esto dentro y fuera del `AppBarLayout`:

```
<include android:layout="@menu/breviario_menu_action" />
```

En ambos casos me marca este error en la línea donde se carga el layout principal:

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: You must specifiy a layout
>   in the include tag:

Y si intento esto:

```
<include layout="@menu/breviario_menu_action" />
```

Me da otro error distinto:

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0:
>   Error inflating class menu

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano, esto que comentas es algo que también trate de realizar hace tiempo!!! :), sin embargo al final lo que realice es inflar un nuevo menú, dependiendo de la Activity o Fragment en el que me encuentro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NO, de hecho es necesario `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` para inflar el menú, ya que al tratar de cargar el menú desde un `include` u otro `layout`, este no puede acceder a su referencia:

```
R.menu.my_menu
```

Con respecto a los [Menús](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) en realidad la forma de cargarlos es como indica [la documentación](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html):

"Cargarlo como un objeto `Menu` en la actividad o el fragmento.", Pero no se puede inflar desde otro `include` o `layout`.

---

**Como complemento esta información:**

> en cada Activity inflo el menú por código.

En realidad lo que mencionas es lo que se realiza comúnmente, pero también puedes cambiar tu menú ocultando y haciendo visibles opciones (indispensable el uso de [invalidateOptionsMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu())):

```
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if(tipoMenu == TIPO_2) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            menu.findItem(R.id.option1).setVisible(false);
            menu.findItem(R.id.option5).setVisible(true);
        }


return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

o cambiar completamente el menú, en este caso primero se elimina y posteriormente se infla el nuevo menú:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if(menuTipo == TIPO_1) {
        menu.clear();
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_a, menu);
    }else if(menuTipo == TIPO_2) {
        menu.clear();
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_b, menu);
    }else if(menuTipo == TIPO_3)
        menu.clear(); //Elimina menú.
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: El hecho es que se trata solamente de ese menú en todas las activitys, no se trata de incorporar otros elementos a un menú ya existente. Es una especie de menú utilitario que ciertas activitys necesitan en el `Toolbar` y que es siempre el mismo y es único. Cuando ese menú no está las activitys no tienen ni necesitan ningún menú.

Comment: Ok, cuando no necesites menú, puedes eliminarlo con :  menu.clear();

Comment: Bueno sí, eso ya lo sabía, de hecho hace un tiempo [respondí una pregunta en ese sentido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/111463/29967). De lo que se trata aquí es solamente de mostrar un menú estático en el ToolBar, no de mostrar u ocultar partes de él. Todo lo que dices de `menu.clear()` creo que sobra en esta respuesta.

Comment: @A.Cedano he editado mi pregunta, gracias!

Comment: Muchas gracias Jorge. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

no se si esto es lo que intentas hacer, pero no creo que sea muy recomendable. El toolbar no deja de ser un contenedor, al cual le puedes agregar mas vistas (ejem: un constraint layout, coordinator, linear, etc) por lo que nada impide que hagas algo asi

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            layout="@layout/test_include"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

test_include.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

La desventaja es que tendrias que utilizar un findviewbyid a cada item y manejar el evento que necesites en cada uno y tener en cuenta cuando son muchos elementos manejar el overflow