# Ocultar y mostrar componente optionsMenu usando kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Aquí tengo un **optionsMenu** en un **activity** que lo creo desde el método **onCreateOptionsMenu**, pero a la hora de que mi **activity** pase por **onStop**, quisiera que este objeto se oculte, y que a la hora de pasar por **onStart** se vuelva a mostrar, ¿alguna idea?
Este es mi código:

```
override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    //TODO("Ocultar onCreateOptionsMenu")
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    //TODO("Mostrar onCreateOptionsMenu")
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.top_menu, menu)
    return true
}
```

Comment: Hola, creo que lo más rápido sería agregar onPrepareOptionsMenu() y dentro establecer la lógica para mostrar/ocultar elementos del menú, revisa mi respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para realizar esto **debes llamar nuevamente `onCreateOptionsMenu()` con la nueva configuración del menú, pero para que lo puedas llamar debes usar  [invalidateOptionsMenu()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#invalidateOptionsMenu()) para que el menú pueda ser recreado**.

> [invalidateOptionsMenu()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#invalidateOptionsMenu()) Declara que el menú de opciones ha
> cambiado, por lo que debe volver a crearse. Se llamará al método
> onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu) la próxima vez que deba
> mostrarse.

La mejor es modificar tu menú agregando `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` y dentro de acuerdo a una variable boolean definir los elementos que desees ocultando/mostrar:

```
   private void modificarMenu = false;
   ...
   ...

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            if(modificarMenu) {
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); //Permite modificar menú.
                menu.findItem(R.id.option1).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.option2).setVisible(true);
            }else{
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); //Permite modificar menú.
                menu.findItem(R.id.option1).setVisible(true);
                menu.findItem(R.id.option2).setVisible(false);
            }
    
           return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
       }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa esta respuesta:
[Android ¿Como modificar menú?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/138035/es-posible-en-android-poner-un-men%C3%BA-en-el-toolbar-directamente-a-trav%C3%A9s-del-arc/138051#138051)

Comment: Entiendo el punto pero aún no me queda muy claro, en el gif al presionar el botón de play tengo entendido que se ejecuta onPrepareOptionsMenu, pero dentro del evento del botón (en mi caso dentro de onCreate y onStart) ¿cómo hago para que se ejecute aquel método?

Comment: Bueno después de unos minutos lo pude ejecutar, se me había ocurrido crear un menu null e inicializarlo en onCreateOptionsMenu, y luego cada vez que quería ocultarlo o mostrarlo llamaba a onPrepareOptionsMenu() y le pasaba el menu que ya tenía, y claro modificando un booleano para que se oculte o se muestre. Gracias por la ayuda :)

Comment: Si usas onStop() y onStart(), entre estos métodos no podrás ver el cambio, te sugiero usar otra opción  usar un boolean para cambiar el menú.

Comment: Ya me había dado cuenta de eso, antes de hacer la pregunta pensaba que al abrirse un fragment sobre un activity este pasaba por esos métodos, pero al parecer no