# android MenuItem setVisible()

Tags: android, menú

Intento que si se cumple una condición, un item del menú lateral de la app no se muestre. No da error, y depurando coge bien el valor del item, pero no hace nada. El código es el siguiente:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    MenuItem mVencidos = menu.findItem(R.id.miMantenimientosVencidos);
    MenuItem iVencidas = menu.findItem(R.id.miInspeccionesVencidas);

    mostarVencidosUsuario(mVencidos);
    mostarVencidosUsuario(iVencidas);

    return true;
}

private void mostarVencidosUsuario(MenuItem item){ 
   // admin es un campo que en este caso si que está a falso
    if(admin == false) {
        item.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Otra opción que probé sin éxito fue esta:
crear 2 menús distintos, uno con todos los items y otro sin los que quiero ocultar. Después cargar uno u otro en función de si se cumple la condición

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    if(admin)
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_admin, menu);
    else
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_no_admin, menu);

    return true;
}
```

He publicado la solución en las respuestas.

Comment: prueba con item.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: Juan, creo que [si haces algo como esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/111463/29967) te resultará. Creo que además es mucho más elegante de ese modo.

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano gracias por tu respuesta, pero no me funciona de esa manera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gracias al enlace en la respuesta de @A.Cedano lo logré del siguiente modo:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    if(admin){
        navigationView.getMenu().clear();
        navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_admin);
    } else {
        navigationView.getMenu().clear();
        navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_no_admin);
    }
    return true;
}
```